# Media player videos are not visible

Tags: android, video, media-player

Hi guys: I created media player application in android and playing video files from localhost. i am accessing localhost url from database in one activity, by using intent i passes  url to media player application. whenever i doing this, i can get audio only. videos are not visible. At the same time i tried to play video indirectly (By pressing play button) it displays the video. I am totally confused. can any one rectify the problem which i am facing now. ??